# A better way to implement Business Logic in MS Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, business-logic

I use C# Entity Framework and Asp.net Web Forms 4.

At the moment I'm developing the Administrator section for a Cms so I have to work with many GridView Controls for CRUD operations on my data.

I use EF as DAL and I implement my Business Logic inside every .aspx page; Pages are organized logically by folders.

My BL are pretty simple like: for User A takes from DB X, Y, Z and display it on a GridView instead for User B takes from DB only X and display on the same GridView.

In my little experience I found my self spending a lot of time in embedding my BL Roles inside each .aspx using Event Triggers Web Form Mechanism. My problem is that same pages could have the same BL and so I have to copy and paste my code in may different .aspx pages.

My questions:

- How can I centralize my Business Logic and display data accordingly in many GridView without implement the BL in every page where the GirdView is codeded?
- I understand a bit about Classes, could make sense implement BL in a Class and attach it to a GridView using the ObjectDataSource? [Example here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/GridviewObjectDataSrc.aspx)
- In your experience what is the better approach to his kind of problems?
- Could MVC approach be a solution?

Thanks for your time on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to layer your application - for example, in a typical scenario, you can have following projects:

- Entities (more correctly DTO (data transfer objects)) and other classes/logic that needs to be used in all other layers
- Data Access Layer that would handle persistence of your entities to data store
- Business Logic Layer
- UI Layer

You are already made choice of EF4 as your DAL. You may use POCO entities (Code-First model) to have your entity/DTO classes in a separate project. As far as your business logic goes, put that in business layer which is actually bunch of classes that would define API. For example,

```
public static class CustomerHelper
{
   public static Customer Get(int customerId)
   {
      // do access control security
      ...
      // use EF4 to get the customer object
   }

   public static void Update(Customer customer)
   {
      // do access control security
      ...
      // use EF4 to update the customer object
   }

}
```

Generally, business layer can have validations, security checks, transaction control, any pre/post processing needed for the business transaction etc.

Finally, your aspx pages will be your UI layer that would use BL classes to get/update the data. For declarative data-binding, you have to use object data source.

Comment: Thanks Vinay, I rally appreciate your help on this

Comment: Sorry Vinay but I read carefully your comment and I'm not able to understand what is a POCO, I mean what I can place there that should not be in the BL?

Comment: @Gibbok, POCO means "plain old c# object". A POCO class represents a business entity and used for transferring the corresponding data. Such class may have validation rules but not processing logic or persistence mechanism. All other layers will use this class for transferring data. In the code from my answer, Customer will be a POCO entity/DTO while CustomerHelper (or CustomerManager) would represent a BL class. See POCO support in EF4: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: Continuing from last comment... see this article for POCO with Code First model: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx  And most importantly, go via this article  to understand design related issue with multi-tier/layer app with EF4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335715.aspx

Comment: Thanks once again for your explanation, have a nice day!